# Can't connect to local gae endpoints from Genymotion emulator

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

It's a simple helloworld project using endpoints generated from `MyBean` and `MyEndpoint` classes which come default with the `Endpoints module`. The emulator I use is Genymotion which I connect to through the **/10.0.2.2** ip. When I access the endpoints server locally **"localhost:8080"** in my web browser it works just fine but when I run/debug it using emulator in **AndroidStudio** I get this timeout exception :

```
-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 20000ms
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at com.serjsmor.anotherbackend.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:25)
    03-03 11:44:30.310    3548-3571/com.serjsmor.anotherbackend W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**client module :**
TestEndpoint.java

```
public class TestEndpoint {

    final MyApi taskApiService;

    // Constructor
    public TestEndpoint () {
        MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl("https://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer( new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest)
                            throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                }

                );
        taskApiService = builder.build();
    } // end of constructor, other methods to follow in this class...
}
```

The actual code to run it :
MainActivity.java

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestEndpoint test = new TestEndpoint();
                try {
                    test.taskApiService.sayHi("sdad").execute();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

**backend module :** 
MyBean.java

```
public class MyBean {

    private String myData;

    public String getData() {
        return myData;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        myData = data;
    }
}
```

MyEndpoint.java

```
@Api(name = "myApi", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "backend.anotherbackend.serjsmor.com", ownerName = "backend.anotherbackend.serjsmor.com", packagePath = ""))
public class MyEndpoint {

    /**
     * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {

        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        response.setData("Hi, " + name);

        return response;
    }
```

Module:app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.serjsmor.anotherbackend"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

Module:backend build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 10.0.2.2 refers to your Genymotion emulator device which is NOT where your dev app engine server is running.
Your dev app engine server should be running on your local desktop computer with a typical ip address like say 192.168.1.100. So do this instead:

.setRootUrl("http://192.168.1.100:8080/_ah/api/")

find out your ip address from windows with 'ipconfig' command in the cmd.exe window. I don't know for other OS. Notice you'll be using 'http' locally, NOT 'https' (which is for accessing the app engine on appspot.com)

All your other code seems RIGHT!

Comment: I thought when you try to refer to your localhost you should point the emulator to 10.0.2.2. I'll switch it in an hour and see if it works. Thanks !

Comment: I pointed on my ipv4 adrdess and it still gives me error. Any idea why?