# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 10000ms

Tags: java, android, rest, timeout

I am trying to connect my android app with my own Rest Service. But i received this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 10000ms
```

This is my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button login, exit, back;
    TextView result;
    OkHttpClient client;
    MediaType JSON;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        client = new OkHttpClient();
        JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    }

    public class GetTask extends AsyncTask {

        private Exception exception;

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {
                String getResponse = get("http://10.0.2.2:8080/ServicioRestTFG/rest/UsuariosServicesRs/");
                return getResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        public String get(String url) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GetTask task = new GetTask();
        task.execute();
    }
```

I have no idea what is the problem. I read that one solution is increase timeout but this not my solution becasuse i try it and it doesnt work for me.

Comment: i solved that with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831375/cant-connect-to-local-gae-endpoints-from-genymotion-emulator.